# Opportunity Validation Rule on Stages and CloseDate

Tags: validation-rule, custom-permission

My validation rule when Stage Name is = Closed-Won I want no user will be able to update to change the Close Date expect users who have this custom permission $Permission.Change_Closed_Date_after_Closed_Won.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually pretty easy:

```
AND(NOT($Permission.Change_Closed_Date_after_Closed_Won), ISCHANGED(StageName), ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName),'Closed-Won'))
```

If the stage was closed won, and the status has changed, and the user does not have the permission, display the error.

Comment: If I want to add more fields on this validation rule so users can't make updates after the stage is closed-won.  Field examples like Amount, New_RAB__c, Existing_RAB__c.

Comment: @Andreg You would use multiple validation rules, one per field. Do not try to cram all the fields into a single rule.

Comment: ok makes sense.  Can you help me? When an opportunity is stage closed-won, the user doesn't have $Permission.Change_Closed_Date_after_Closed_Won and they try to change field New_RAB__c.

Comment: Never mind.  I got it.